# Somthing wrong with using CSV as database for a webapp?

Tags: python, csv, web-applications, flask

I am using Flask to make a small webapp to manage a group project, in this website I need to manage attendances, and also meetings reports. I don't have the time to get into SQLAlchemy, so I need to know what might be the bad things about using CSV as a database.

Comment: no concurrency, slow/difficult to update rows, can't do queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do it, CSV that is.

There are *many* other possibilities, for instance the [sqlite](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3) database, python [shelve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html#module-shelve), etc. The available options from the standard library are summarised [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/persistence.html#data-persistence).

Given that your application is a webapp, you will need to consider the effect of concurrency on your solution to ensure data integrity. You could also consider a more powerful database such as postgres for which there are a number of python libraries.

Answer (score 7):

Just don't do it.

The problem with CSV is …

a, **concurrency is not possible**: What this means is that when two people access your app at the same time, there is no way to make sure that they don't interfere with each other, making changes to each other's data. There is no way to solve this with when using a CSV file as a backend.

b, **speed**: Whenever you make changes to a CSV file, you need to reload more or less the whole file. Parsing the file is eating up both memory and time.

Databases were made to solve this issues.

I agree however, that you don't need to learn SQLAlchemy for a small app.

There are lightweight alternatives that you should consider.

What you are looking for are ORM - Object-relational mapping - who translate Python code into SQL and manage the SQL databases for you.

[PeeweeORM](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and [PonyORM](http://ponyorm.com/). Both are easy to use and translate all SQL into Python and vice versa. Both are free for personal use, but Pony costs money if you use it for commercial purposes. I highly recommend PeeweeORM. You can start using SQLite as a backend with Peewee, or if your app grows larger, you can plug in MySQL or PostGreSQL easily.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's nothing wrong with that as long as you abstract away from it. I.e. make sure you have a clean separation between what you write and how you implement i . That will bloat your code a bit, but it will make sure you can swap your CSV storage in a matter of days.

I.e. pretend that you can persist your data as if you're keeping it in memory. Don't write "openCSVFile" in you flask app. Use initPersistence(). Don't write "csvFile.appendRecord()". Use "persister.saveNewReport()". When and if you actually realise CSV to be a bottleneck, you can just write a new persister plugin.

There are added benefits like you don't have to use a mock library in tests to make them faster. You just provide another persister.

Answer (score 0):

I am absolutely *baffled* by how many people discourage using CSV as an database storage back-end format.

1. Concurrency: There is *****NO***** reason why CSV can not be used with concurrency.  Just like how a database thread can write to one area of a binary file at the same time that another thread writes to another area of the same binary file.  **Databases can do *EXACTLY* the same thing with CSV files.**  Just as a journal is used to maintain the atomic nature of individual transactions, the *same exact thing can be done with CSV*.
2. Speed: Why on earth would a database read and write a *WHOLE* file at a time, when **the database can do what it does for *ALL* other database storage formats**, look up the starting byte of a record in an index file and ***SEEK*** to it in constant time and **overwrite the data and comment out anything left over and record the free space for latter use in a separate index file, *just like a database could zero out the bytes of any unneeded areas of a binary "row" and record the free space in a separate index file***... I just do not understand this hostility to non-binary formats, when everything that can be done with one format can be done with the other... ***everything***, except perhaps raw binary data compression, depending on the particular CSV syntax in use (special binary comments... etc.).
3. Emergency access: The added benefit of CSV is that when the database dies, which inevitably happens, you are left with a CSV file that can still be accessed quickly in the case of an emergency... which is the primary reason I do not **EVER** use binary storage for essential data that should be quickly accessible even when the database breaks due to incompetent programming.

Yes, the CSV file would have to be re-indexed every time you made changes to it in a spread sheet program, but that is no different than having to re-index a binary database after the index/table gets corrupted/deleted/out-of-sync/etc./etc..